# Is there any possibility to spawn new window in tkinter on the same screen as his parent?

Tags: python, tkinter, window, screen, toplevel

I'm using python tkinter on Windows and I want to spawn a new Toplevel window on the same screen as his parent. For example when user has 2 monitors I want to spawn every new window on the same monitor as main app window.

Is there any possibility to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the parent window's pixel coordinates by `winfo_x` and `winfo_y`, and then spawn the `Toplevel` at the same location.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def get_geometry():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.geometry(f"+{root.winfo_x()}+{root.winfo_y()}")
    top.title("This is new toplevel")

tk.Button(root,text="Spawn new window",command=get_geometry).pack()

root.mainloop()
```